# MATLAB - Get rid of leading zeros in each row of matrix, 1 at a time?

Tags: matlab, matrix, sparse-matrix, leading-zero

I want to get rid of leading zeros in each row of a matrix, but limit it to eliminating one zero at a time.

This is my current solution, but is there a simpler way of doing it?

```
a = [ 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
      0 0 5 2 3 4 0 0 0 0
      0 0 0 1 2 3 4 0 0 0
      0 0 1 2 3 0 0 0 0 0
      0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0
      1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ]

  b=zeros(size(a));
  for j=1:size(a,2)
  for i=1:size(a,1)
      temp=find(a(i,:),1,'first');
      candelete=min(2,temp);
      b(i,1:end-candelete+1)=a(i,candelete:end);
  end
  a=b
  end
```

EDIT:
I'm want to print every iteration, so that the first output will only have the first leading zero removed:

```
 0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
 0     5     2     3     4     0     0     0     0     0
 0     0     1     2     3     4     0     0     0     0
 0     1     2     3     0     0     0     0     0     0
 0     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0
 1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
```

the second will have 2 zeros removed, and so on...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT:** Now that the question was clarified, here's a better answer using [`circshift`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/circshift.html):

```
index = (a(:, 1) == 0) & any(a, 2);
while any(index)
  a(index, :) = circshift(a(index, :), -1, 2);
  disp(a);
  index = (a(:, 1) == 0) & index;
end
```

Comment: Thanks, but is there a way to have it print the matrix with only the first leading zero removed? I want it to print every iteration, up to your solution.

Comment: oh, I got it:  a(i, :) = circshift(a(i, :), max(1-startIndex(i),-1))

Comment: @RootFAIL: I think my updated answer is what you're looking for.